# How to deal with "undefined" and "NaN" in simple javascript calculations?

Tags: javascript

So two dropdowns and a few javascript functions to choose a price and set a country (which comes with a tax rate). Then display the price + tax rate = total to the user on the payment form.

If a price and a country(tax rate) are selected, the javascript and the sums work, thusly:

```
£49.99 + 10% VAT = £54.99
```

If a price but no country(tax rate) are selected, this happens:

```
Total: £49.99 + undefined% VAT = £NaN
```

And if neither a price or a country(tax rate) are selected, then we get:

```
£undefined + undefined% VAT = £NaN
```

So the question is: how do we deal with those ugly errors from javascript? What's the javascript way to deal with if/else for `undefined` and `NaN`?

Thanks.

**UPDATE 2:** the NaN check works, but where do I put the undefined check. Have added the TaxPrice function so you can see where it is coming from.

```
// First grab the tax rate from a drop down

function TaxPrice()
{
var taxprice=0;
var theForm = document.forms["payment-form"];
var selectedrate = theForm.elements["country_vat"];
taxprice = tax_rates[selectedrate.value];
return taxprice;
}

// Then calculate the total, including the NaN checks

function calculateTotal()
{
var TaxRate = TaxPrice() / 100;
var TotalPrice = PlanPrice() + (TaxRate * PlanPrice());
var TotalTax = (TaxRate * PlanPrice())

if(isNaN(TotalPrice)) {
    // check NaN
    TotalPrice = 0
}

if(isNaN(TotalTax)) {
    // check NaN
    TotalTax = 0
}

//display the price
var divobj = document.getElementById('p');
divobj.innerHTML = "£" + PlanPrice();

//display the tax rate
var divobj = document.getElementById('r');
divobj.innerHTML = "£" + TotalTax.toFixed(2) + " (" + TaxPrice() + "% VAT)";

//display the total
var divobj = document.getElementById('t');
divobj.innerHTML = "£" + TotalPrice.toFixed(2);    

}
```

Comment: Check for that in and if/else statement and do whatever accordingly?

Comment: Don't perform the calculation unless you have valid input. use `=== undefined` fo evaluate undefined and [isNaN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN) for not a number. Also read about [truthy/falsy](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/truthy-falsey/). It would also help if you provided us with your javascript.

Comment: Have added the calculation bit.

Comment: Almost. Where do I put the undefined check?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check specifically for `undefined` with

```
if(typeof price === "undefined"){}
```

Check specifically for `NaN` with

```
if(isNaN(price)){}
```

Generally you can also simply do

```
if(price){}
```

Where the inside of the if statement will return  `false` if `price` is `NaN`, `undefined` or `null`, but also when it is `0` or empty string, which you may not want so you'd need to specify it in the condition.

---

Specifically in your case, it would be good not to perform the calculations when either of its parts is not defined as the result will only create `undefined` or `NaN` values anyway:

```
function calculateTotal(){
    //first check all you need for the calculation is defined
    if (typeof TaxPrice() != 'undefined' && typeof PlanPrice() != 'undefined'){
        //perform the calculation and output the result
    }else{
        //output an error message or a default ouput
    }
}
```

Then you don't have to check for `NaN`'s because those were caused by making arithmetics with `undefined`'s.

Comment: Almost. Where do I put the undefined check?

Comment: It's best when you check for undefined before the calculations so you won't have to check for NaN's. Check my edit @MatthewBennett

Comment: Thank you Ko, that worked. Put the maths above the conditional in the end to try to save some code. And then an onload on the body for that page so it will do a default calculation first.

Answer (score 1):

Please covert value to a finite number, for example:

```
function toNumber(value) {
    if(typeof  value !== 'number') {
        // covert type to number
        // void 0, null, true, false, 'abc', [], {} => NaN
        // [0] => 0
        value = parseFloat(value)
    }
    if(isNaN(value)) {
        // check NaN
        value = 0
    }
    if(!isFinite(value)) {
        // check Infinity and -Infinity
        value = Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER * Math.sign(value)
    }
    return value
}
```

Answer (score 0):

make a function similar to this

```
function get_value(input, default_value) {
    return input === undefined || isNaN(input) ? default_value : input;
}
```

and then use it whenever you need to do calculations with a possible undefined value. Eg

```
var a = 10;

var sum = a + get_value(b, 0); // b is undefined and get_Value returns 0, sum is 10

var prod = a * get_value(b, 1); // b is undefined and get_Value returns 1, prod is 10
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the isNaN() function to check if a variable is NaN.

e.g. see here: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_isnan.asp

You could also track which vars were set in additional vars. ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you want calculation to be done only when both of them are selected, then simply check for these errors in front of your code by:

```
if(typeof (your_price_variable) !== undefined && typeof (your_country_variable) !== undefined)
```

and make the function only run when this condition is met. Then the output won't be "NaN."

Comment: Would you put this within the CalculateTotal function somewhere, or before it?